# javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname XXX not verified, for no self-signed cert

Tags: java, android, https, okhttp

#### Problem

Recently I noticed that 1-0.5% of all users faced with `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException` during simple `GET` over `HTTPS`.

But they looks interesting: exception message contains certificates information and according to this information certs doesn't related to my server, example of exceptions is:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname XXX not verified:
>       certificate: sha256/AUSXlKDCf1X30WhWeAWbjToABfBkJrKWPL6KwEi5VH0=
>       DN: CN=hautdebitmobile.orange.fr,OU=Orange France,O=Orange,L=Paris,ST=Paris,C=FR
>       subjectAltNames: [hautdebitmobile.orange.fr]
>
> javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname XXX not verified:
>       certificate: sha256/LKtpdq9q7F7msGK0w1+b/gKoDHaQcZKTHIf9PTz2u+U=
>       DN: CN=wireless.wifirst.net,OU=Gandi Standard SSL,OU=Domain Control Validated
>       subjectAltNames: [wireless.wifirst.net, www.wireless.wifirst.net]
>
> javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname XXX not verified:
>       certificate: sha256/TfZXN7z9Tky/Z84sfOJcq4lhD3kNY4fPp3gKUZ27ekE=
>       DN: CN=*.internet-access.center,OU=Gandi Standard Wildcard SSL,OU=Domain Control Validated
>       subjectAltNames: [*.internet-access.center, internet-access.center]
>
> javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname XXX not verified:
>       certificate: sha256/Bx0LzMlqtgOKRIfUR4cQfb7yDy+3iotESgqk9HvWTOA=
>       DN: CN=*.nomosphere.fr,OU=Gandi Standard Wildcard SSL,OU=Domain Control Validated
>       subjectAltNames: [*.nomosphere.fr, nomosphere.fr]
>
> javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname XXX not verified:
>       certificate: sha256/zaV2Aw1A742R1+WpXWvL5atsJbGmeSS6dzZOfe6f1Yw=
>       DN: CN=login.globalsuite.net,OU=COMODO SSL Unified Communications,OU=Domain Control Validated
>       subjectAltNames: [login.globalsuite.net, *.gtkcentral.net, *.gtkserver.net]
>
> javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname XXX not verified:
>       certificate: sha256/UwOkRGMlP0K/mKNJdpQ0sTg2ean9Tje8UTOvFYzt1GE=
>       DN: CN=login.netinary.net,OU=Security,O=NETINARY,L=MARSEILLE,ST=Bouches-du-Rhône,C=FR
>       subjectAltNames: [login.netinary.net]

At first look these certs looks like random, but after quick research I have found that domains which mentioned there related to internet providers

#### Question

- Is it possible case that this exception happens when end user haven't access to internet and it's just redirected to an provider specific site (to login, or put some money into account)?

Comment: It strongly looks like an intermediate "portal" uses a selfsigned certificate which is not accepted by Java (by default).

Comment: @UwePlonus thanks, so my assumption may be right?

Comment: @UwePlonus You are right, If you will write an answer I will accept it

Comment: @CAMOBAP: so did you find a workaround to fix this case?

Comment: @anthony, I think there is no workaround except propper exception handling if host in error message doesn't related to your server infrastructure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption could be right.

It looks like there is a Man in the Middle (MitM) intercepting the traffic which creates a certificate (either selfsigned or by a intermediate CA) that is not accepted by Java.

Java, by default, only accepts certificates from trusted CAs at the root. The trusted certificates are located in the file `cacerts` in your Java installation.